# Insufficient nominees for moderator election: What happens next?

Tags: discussion, moderation, election

Stack Exchange’s position is that every site has a team of moderators to operate in our network. Currently, this community is being moderated by [Grinch91](https://poker.meta.stackexchange.com/users/3538/grinch91) and [Jon](https://poker.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1762/jon), who have been doing an excellent job. In 2021, Poker [shed its Beta label along with 28 other SE sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331708/congratulations-to-our-29-oldest-beta-sites-theyre-now-no-longer-beta). We recently attempted to hold an election for your community in [October](https://poker.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340/2023-community-moderator-election).

Unfortunately, we only had one individual nominate themselves for the available slot; in this case we would require at least two people to nominate themselves for the available slot, so that the election would be competitive. Members of an SE site being willing to step up as moderators has been the primary threshold for keeping a site alive since [we created this policy in January 2015](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites). Without that, a site is in danger of being shut down. Today, I am posting on behalf of the Community Management team to discuss the next election for this site. In order for a future election to be successful, there need to be community members who are eligible to serve as moderators who are willing to step up to the plate.

### Next Steps

We are going to recommend waiting until April 2024 before setting up another election for this site. We’ll be looking for additional individuals to nominate themselves as moderators to join the team. This next election will help to bring those folks in. If we can’t find at least four people willing to nominate themselves to be a moderator on this site by that time, the site is at risk of shutting down.

Do you have any questions about the election process, or any concerns keeping you from nominating yourself as a moderator? Let us know, and we’ll do our best to address them.

Answer (score 0):

The bold part of the question you linked says, "If there's enough moderation for a public beta site to consistently remain free of spam, for flags to be cleared, and for our Code of Conduct to be upheld, your site will remain open." (sic.) Nowhere out of the post you linked as a source for the "four moderators in total required" really mentions the number of 4 - so why not just have 3? It's not exactly intuitive to me that we're getting so much activity for 3 moderators to not be cutting it in terms of having humans on the other end to review flags.

Comment: Correct, the site is not currently at risk of closure; we can continue to run the site with two mods. However, for an election to be considered competitive, there needs to be one person running for each spot plus one so the election is competitive. Since only one person nominated themselves for the spot, it wasn't competitive, and the election failed. For Poker we are trying to get to 3 mods, not 4.

Comment: Though looks like I didn't clarify in my post that there was only one slot up for grabs. Which is my bad as I didn't catch that.

Comment: On that point of running it with 2, I agree we can continue, but I would also still strongly recommend others who are interested in stepping up!