# Why don't you want to moderate for Poker

Tags: discussion, moderation, election

A few weeks ago, [we announced](https://poker.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342/insufficient-nominees-for-moderator-election-what-happens-next) to the Poker community that we had trouble getting the necessary number of nominations to hold a competitive election. We hoped that this would start a conversation on the need for nominations for moderators on the site.

We have greatly appreciated Grinch91 and Jons’s work to keep the site well moderated. We need the election to be competitive to hold one. Since this is a post-graduation election, it has to be competitive to be successful. If we have another unsuccessful election, Poker will have an uncertain future that could lead it to being close at some point.

**So why don't you want to moderate for Poker?**

Answer (score 2):

> So why don't you want to moderate for Poker?

At this point I don't qualify because youneed 300 rep. With experience as a moderator and expertise with poker necessary to genuinely moderate the site, though, this is only a technical limitation.

Even if I did meet the bar, I wouldn't do it. That would mean Poker SE kept running, and it seems at this point more clearly than ever, Stack Exchange needs to start culling the sites that don't work.

Poker SE does not have the content to justify a separate site.

- From SEDE's latest infornation, Poker SE has less than 2200 questions and 4700 answers to match, across 133 tags.
- The single tag of Magic: the Gathering on Board & Card Games SE, which sees repeated Area 51 proposals for a separate site, has nearly 5000 questions, and 8700 answers to them.

Poker SE does not have the user base necessary to be called a community.

- Far less than half of the new users in the last 45 days are legitimate. 18 are explicitly identified with "spam" or "spammer" in their username.
- Of those new users, only six have received any rep on the site (via joint total of seven upvotes) (and one other user has even lost rep from their association bonus).
- In this quarter, only nine users have gained the reputation equivalent of at least two upvotes.
- During this time, 21 others have gained the equivalent of exactly one upvote.

Comment: I think this post has the crux of the issue. I feel most of the time it's closing the same does this hand beat this by new accounts. I'm happy to do so, but I'm wondering if perhaps expanding the community to be more than just poker would be good. I do feel there is valid and great content being posted, but it's been lesser and more sparse than in previous years. I could understand not wanting a SE for it, but I think expanding the Poker one to cover more general gambling or gambling card games may increase the community.

Comment: At which point you're just expanding into the Board & Card Games space instead of seeing this site's scope as being a strict subset of that one... I don't think it would solve the problem of there not being enough audience coming to Stack Exchange for that content and information alone, competing with how many thousands of sites that allow for discussion and networking and competition, being attractive in ways SE just can't (and shouldn't and hopefully won't try).

Comment: Fair point as well Nij.

Answer (score 0):

I had considered it, but I am not that active on here anymore. Also, I'm not sure how qualified I am to be a mod.

Answer (score 0):

> So why don't you want to moderate for Poker?

Mostly active on other stacks, here, I read questions, and sometimes answer, but a lack of rep points is not a good thing. Even if you have knowledge of the SE system, you must probably be known and trusted by users of *this* community before you run for anything. Earning points is one of them, and many of us can't easily (check the top [users' rep for 2023](https://poker.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=year)).

In this case, helping (answer, flag... if there are enough things to do, questions to answer) is always an option, running for an election a far less valuable one :)